# How to get an index of different category returned by "order by" sql in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

We can easily get a sql result as following:

```
SQL>select Name, Value from table order by Name;

Name   Value
------------
A      1
A      2
B      1
C      5
C      6
C      7
```

However, is there a way to link the name to a number so that an index of different names can be formed? Suppose we don't know how many different names are in the table and don't know what they are.

```
Name   Value  idx
-----------------
A      1      0 
A      2      0
B      1      1
C      5      2
C      6      2
C      7      2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be done using a window function:

```
select Name, 
       Value, 
       dense_rank() over (order by name) - 1 as idx
from table 
order by Name;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I want!