# Is there a way to implement dense_rank() in hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Based on my previous post:
[How to get an index of different category returned by "order by" sql in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444505/how-to-get-an-index-of-different-category-returned-by-order-by-sql-in-oracle)

I want to use Hibernate to return the result of this query from my oracle database. It seems that Hibernate doesn't support this feature in its native query creation. Is there a way to do this in Hibernate?

```
public List<Object[]> testQuery() {
        String queryStr = "select Name, Value, dense_rank() over (order by name) - 1 as idx " 
                        + "from table order by Name;"

        Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(queryStr);    
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

I got an error like following:

```
Jul 19, 2016 10:14:17 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 933, SQLState: 42000
<Jul 19, 2016 10:14:17 AM PDT> <Warning> <org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter> <BEA-000000> <SQL Error: 933, SQLState: 42000> 
Jul 19, 2016 10:14:17 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

<Jul 19, 2016 10:14:17 AM PDT> <Error> <org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter> <BEA-000000> <ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Or if this is too complicated to implement, is there an alternative way to solve the problem in my initial post?

Comment: Remove a semicolon from the end of this line: `+ "from table order by Name;"` and try again. In other words - replace this line with: `+ "from table order by Name"`

Comment: Thanks! It was the reason.